# XNA : Is there a way to prevent other items(sprites) when dragging?

Tags: c#, xna, hover, mouse, drag

I was looking for a way to block other object from the same class to be dragged, when I begin dragging one and hover another it id dragged as well...

Here is my main item definition,

```
class DrawableObject 
{
public Rectangle RectObject

public void Update(GameTime gameTime, MouseState ms)
        {
            if ((ButtonState.Pressed == Mouse.GetState().LeftButton))
                if (RectObject.Intersects(new Rectangle(ms.X, ms.Y, 0, 0)))
                    Dragged = true;
            else
                Dragged = false;
                if (Dragged)
                    RectObject = new Rectangle(ms.X - RectObject.Width / 2, ms.Y - RectObject.Height / 2, RectObject.Width, RectObject.Height);               
        }
}
```

The issue will be more tight as I will be creating more than 50 instance of this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep a "global" property with the current object being dragged.

Then before accepting dragging each object will check if another is not yet dragged:

```
public void Update(GameTime gameTime, MouseState ms)
{
    if (currentObject != null && this != currentObject) return;

    if ((ButtonState.Pressed == Mouse.GetState().LeftButton))
    {
        if (RectObject.Intersects(new Rectangle(ms.X, ms.Y, 0, 0)))
        {
            Dragged = true;
            currentObject = this;
        }
    }
    else
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this,
But I know this method and I was looking for an alternative or better one if possible.

Comment: This method is simple, fast and explicit. :)

Comment: hhhhmmmmmm
I did it at first time but I taught that it will be move memory heavy since my object will have nearly 6000 instance in some part of the game
Anyway thank you @Pragmateek :)

Comment: One day a wise man said: "premature optimization is the root of all evil"; so wait for the issues to appear before trying to fix them. ;)

Comment: hahahahahaha yeah right, it's my first try fro XNA and want to go until I complete this game and to publish it. I used a little of Allegro and SDL with c++ more than 6 years ago and all must be handled manually so this is my root of evil :D.